# WMI strange values

Tags: c++, windows, wmi, ram

I want to detect the `RAM` manufacturer in `WMI`. The problem that I get strange symbols instead of actual data. Also I have checked it using `wmic` command. Screenshots are listed below.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

I have tried different approaches to check value before output, but the problem is still present.

**Code:**

```
VARIANT ramManufacturer;
pclsObj->Get(L"Manufacturer", 0, &ramManufacturer, 0, 0);
QString userRAMManufacturer;
QStringList ramProperty;
QStringList ramData;

   if (SysStringLen(ramManufacturer.bstrVal) != 0) {
       userRAMManufacturer = QString::fromWCharArray(ramManufacturer.bstrVal);

        if (!userRAMManufacturer.isEmpty()) {
            ramProperty << QObject::tr("Manufacturer");
            ramData << userRAMManufacturer;
        }
    }
```

Or

```
if (CComBSTR(ramManufacturer.bstrVal).Length() != 0) {
    userRAMManufacturer = QString::fromWCharArray(ramManufacturer.bstrVal);

    if (!userRAMManufacturer.isEmpty()) {
        ramProperty << QObject::tr("Manufacturer");
        ramData << userRAMManufacturer;
    }
}
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, you aren't checking the return value from `Get` call to see if it actually succeeded.  So your `VARIANT ramManufacturer` variable is initialized with garbage.   Nor are you checking the `vt` member of the VARIANT returned by `Get` to see if it's actually `VT_BSTR` instead of an ascii string or something else.

Comment: @selbie

Ok. I will check it. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@selbie

Thank you. I have checked for `Get` value and now the values are correct.

**Code:**

```
if (ramManufacturer.vt != VT_NULL && ramManufacturer.vt == VT_BSTR) {
    userRAMManufacturer = QString::fromWCharArray(ramManufacturer.bstrVal);
    ramProperty << QObject::tr("Manufacturer");
    ramData << userRAMManufacturer;
}
```